# Social Media Buttons Positioning

Tags: css, css-position

How do you position social media buttons on the side of your content div?
Like here: http://adidasgolf.eu/home.aspx

Absolute positioning? But then the content div has to be positioned absolutely as well right?
This is what I have so far... without the social media buttons.

http://www.swiftgeckotech.com/golf01.html

Thanks.

Comment: check out `position: relative` and perform some Javascript calculations to deal with positioning and potentially hide if the screen is too small.

Answer (score 0):

The content div does not to be positioned absolutely to do so with the social icons. You are free to keep normal layout in the content div and put the social icons outside the content div, and position them absolutely. You may have to do some z-indexing to get that layered effect as well.

Comment: But what if I change the window size or screen resolution?

Comment: I got them positioned but if I resize window the position changes. What should I do?

Comment: you need position relative. Have you done any reading on position elements with css? Or you could always look at the code of the web page you are trying to emulate you know...

Comment: Use developer tools like Firebug in Firefox, or the pre included chrome ones. Then you just right click on what you want to know about. Done.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to use `position: relative;` for the content `DIV`. Setting the content `DIV` to either `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;` will establish a new origin for the positioning of child elements… See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NwQ3c/) for a quick demonstration of how an absolutely positioned element behaves inside another positioned element.

However, elements with `position: absolute;` are removed from the document flow… They do not have "substance" in terms of pushing other content around on the page. You most likely don't want to set your content `DIV` as `position: absolute;` for this reason. If you were to add more content after that `DIV`, it wouldn't end up at the bottom of the page as expected, but would instead end up behind the absolutely positioned content `DIV`. `position: relative;` will work as expected however, and will give you a new coordinate system to absolutely position your social media buttons to it's side.

Comment: Thanks. The social buttons weren't a child element, so there was part of the problem.